# Eventually, emacsclient -nw freezes?

Tags: terminal-emacs, emacs-daemon

I use `emacs --daemon` to launch GUI clients when using emacs.

Recently I started to use `emacsclient -nw` to launch the TUI version of emacs within tmux. It works great. Eventually though, whether I am in tmux or not, emacs will freeze.

I cannot press anything and any new `emacsclient -nw` instance I start is frozen from launch.

What are the steps to troubleshoot this?